# Call a method of CIM_DataFile object

Tags: c++, methods, call, wmi

I got a `CIM_DataFile` object, received from a `WMI` query.

I want to call a method of that object, for example `Delete` - I'm searching for days now and couldn't find an answer to how I do that in c++ (it is literally 4 lines in Python)

This is my code so far, I'm successfully receiving the file `CIM_DataFile`

```
#include <Windows.h>  
#include <iostream>  
#include <WbemCli.h>  

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")  

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::endl;

    HRESULT hRes = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hRes))
    {
        cout << "Unable to launch COM: 0x" << std::hex << hRes << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if ((FAILED(hRes = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CONNECT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE, 0))))
    {
        cout << "Unable to initialize security: 0x" << std::hex << hRes << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    IWbemLocator* pLocator = NULL;
    if (FAILED(hRes = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pLocator))))
    {
        cout << "Unable to create a WbemLocator: " << std::hex << hRes << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    IWbemServices* pService = NULL;
    if (FAILED(hRes = pLocator->ConnectServer(L"root\\CIMV2", NULL, NULL, NULL, WBEM_FLAG_CONNECT_USE_MAX_WAIT, NULL, NULL, &pService)))
    {
        pLocator->Release();
        cout << "Unable to connect to \"CIMV2\": " << std::hex << hRes << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    if (FAILED(hRes = pService->ExecQuery(L"WQL", L"SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Name = \"C:\\\\deleteme.txt\"", WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY, NULL, &pEnumerator)))
    {
        pLocator->Release();
        pService->Release();
        cout << "Unable to retrive CIM_DataFile: " << std::hex << hRes << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    IWbemClassObject* clsObj = NULL;
    int numElems;
    while ((hRes = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &clsObj, (ULONG*)&numElems)) != WBEM_S_FALSE)
    {
        if (FAILED(hRes))
            break;

        // HERE I SHOULD GET THE CIM_DataFile.DELETE METHOD SOMEHOW

        clsObj->Release();
    }

    pEnumerator->Release();
    pService->Release();
    pLocator->Release();
    return 0;
}
```